# Running functions on all files in a directory and extracting with file name preserved in R

Tags: r, csv, directory, lapply

In R, I wish to extract each `csv` file in my directory, one at a time, as data frames and perform some simple cross-column calculations, then export the resulting dataframe as a `csv` while preserving part of the original file name.

For example in `Path/To/Directory` I have the following 4 files:

```
Prot1-Combined_Scores.csv
Prot2-Combined_Scores.csv
Prot3-Combined_Scores.csv
Prot4-Combined_Scores.csv
```

Each file has a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
       V1    V2 V3 V4        V5       V6       V7
1 CHEM001 0.000  0  0  0.684255  0.91599 0.671794
2 CHEM002 0.048  4  1         0 0.953549 0.691595
3 CHEM003 0.287  1  0  0.011915 0.970648 0.854309
4 CHEM004 0.298  0  2  0.136784 0.984207  0.86979
5 CHEM005 0.000  1  0  0.578534 0.995675 0.695794
```

I want to make a column `V8` that, for example, calculates `(V2+V3+V6+V7)^2 + 2*V4 + V5/3`.

Finally I would like to save the final dataframe as a `csv` file with a name that preserves the `Prot1` part of the original filename, such as `Prot1-Final_Score.csv`, and the same for `Prot2`, `Prot3`, and so on.

I am new to R and I have read that `lapply` is useful for running functions on every file in a directory, but I particularly need help to integrate the calculations I mentioned into `lapply` and also to extract the necessary string from the filename to export later.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps! please also share your efforts or your approach so that you can learn better!

```
path="Path/To/Directory/"
x=list.files(path = path, pattern = ".csv")
final_pathname = paste0(path, x)

L=lapply(seq_along(final_pathname), abc)

abc <- function(i){
  df = read.csv(final_pathname[i])
  df$V8 = (df$V2+df$V3+df$V6+df$V7)^2 + 2*df$V4 + df$V5/3)
  write.csv(df,file = paste0(path,paste0(unlist(strsplit(x[i],".csv"))
                                     ,"-Final_copy"),".csv"))
}
```